# Alternative to diff with progress for massive directory compare?

Tags: rsync, diff

I just rsync-ed 2,000,000 files (3TB) from one RAID to another.

I want to make sure my data is intact.

`rsync -c` takes a really long time.

`diff` doesn't show me what it's doing.

Is there an alternative that's (a) faster, and (b) will show me progress while it's comparing?

(I'm on Mac, and `brew search diff` gives me `apgdiff       colordiff   diffstat    diffutils   fmdiff      libxdiff    open-vcdiff podiff      rfcdiff     vbindiff
bsdiff      diffpdf     diffuse     dwdiff      kdiff3      ndiff       perceptualdiff  rdiff-backup    tkdiff      wdiff`
 ... would one of these do the job?)

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/708001/alternative-to-diff-with-progress-for-massive-directory-compare. Keep questions to 1 exchange site.

Comment: Calculate the sha1sums for both sets of files and then diff the chucksums?

Comment: I agree with Zoredache. Using sha1sum or md5sum to compute unique file hashs on both hosts and then using diff to compare the result is the less network heavy solution. Although i believe it will not be much faster/better than rsync -c.

Comment: Both RAIDs are local. Network traffic not an issue.

Comment: Please [do not crosspost](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/111251/12779).

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111251/alternative-to-diff-with-progress-for-massive-directory-compare which has more answers

Answer (score 2):

`cmp` is the tool you're probably looking for: it compares two files byte by byte, reading one block of each at a time. As soon as it finds a difference, it bails out. It's hence both faster (doesn't require to read whole files when they differ) and more reliable (it actually performs byte by byte comparison) than checksumming. It's also faster than `diff` as it doesn't require complex compuation to show you *where* the files differ.

You could easily write a small script to recurse over your two directories and output progress based on the amount of files (or their cumulative size) processed.